# Find the minimum number of tanks to hold the maximum quantity of wines, at each tank maximum possible capacity

Tags: optimization, algorithms

My business is in the wine reselling business, and we have this problem I've been trying to solve. We have 50 - 70 types of wine to be stored at any time, and around 500 tanks of various capacity. Each tank can only hold 1 type of wine. My job is to determine the minimum number of tanks to hold the maximum number of type of wines, each filled as close to its maximum capacity as possible, i.e 100l of wine should not be stored in a 200l tank if 2 tanks of 60l and 40l also exist.

I've been doing the job by hand in excel and want to try to automate the process, but using macros and array formulas quickly get out of hand. I can write a simple program in C and Swift, but stuck at finding a general algorithm. And pointer on where I can start is much appreciated. A full solution and I will send you a bottle ;)

For clarification, I do know how many types of wine I have and their total quantity, i.e Pinot at 700l, Merlot 2000l, etc. These change every week. The tanks however have many different capacities (40, 60, 80, 100, 200 liters etc) and change at irregular interval since they have to be taken out for cleaning and replaced. Simply using 70 tanks to hold 70 types is not possible.

Also, total quantity of wine never matches total tanks' capacity, and I need to use the minimum number of tanks to hold the maximum amount of wine. In case of insufficient capacity the amount of wine left over must be smallest possible (they'll spoil quickly). If there is left-over, the amount left over of each type must be proportional to their quantity.

A simplified example of the problem is below:

Wine:
Merlot  100
Pinot   120
Tocai   230
Chardonay   400

Total: 850L

Tanks: 
T1  10
T2  20
T3  60
T4  150
T5  80
T6  80
T7  90
T8  80
T9  50
T10 110
T11 50
T12 50

Total   830L

Answer (score 1):

You need a linear program with a binary variable.

$x_{ij}=\begin{cases} \text{1, if wine i is stored in tank j} \\ \text{0, else}  \end{cases}$

$c_j$:=capacity of tank j

$w_i$:=amount of wine i

n=amount of tanks

m=amount of type of wines

$\color{blue}{\texttt{constraints}}$

Sum of the tanks, in which wine i is stored has to be greater or equal than the amount of wine j:

$\sum_{j=1}^n c_j\cdot x_{ij} \geq w_i \quad \forall i \in \{1,2,\ldots , m \}$

A tank can be filled by only one type of wine:

$\sum_{i=1}^m x_{ij}=1 \quad \forall j \in \{1,2,\ldots , n \}$

$\color{blue}{\texttt{objective function}}$:

The sum of used tank has to be minimized.

$\texttt{min} \ \ \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n  x_{ij}$

And finally $x_{ij} \geq 0 $.

The part below I do not really understand. Could you give a numerical example ?

> If there is left-over, the amount left over of each type must be
>   proportional to their quantity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That part means for example if there are 100L of Pinot and 200L of Merlot, if both have leftovers, the qty of should be 10L and 20L to equal 10% of each (or 5%, 2% etc) or close to it.

Comment: @Van Please edit your question to include that useful example.